# Results on normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $B= A^*A$ where $A$ is a normal linear operator on a hilbert space $X$.

Then how can I show that $||{B^2}^n||^{\frac{1}{2^n}} = ||B||?$

I tried using induction but am not able to get anything.

Further using this, how can I show that $||{A^2}^n|| = {||A||^2}^n$?

For the latter, Since $A$ is normal, I have derived that $||{A^2}^n||^2 = {||A||^2}^{n+1}$

Comment: It's enough to show $\|A^2\|=\|A\|^2$ for a normal operator $A$, from which both follows. (Note that $A^k$ is also normal.)

Comment: Normal doesn't make sense for a normed space X, only for a Hilbert Space.